# How do I make Perl::Critic show the offending policy in its output?

Tags: perl, configuration, perl-critic

I've been told it's possible to have [`Perl::Critic`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Perl%3a%3aCritic) show the policy name that is offending in its output. But I can't recall what I have to do to turn this on. How can this be enabled in a `perlcritic.rc`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `--verbose` command-line option can control this-- if you don't want to specify your own format, try the values `8` or `9`. Both of these built-in formats contain the policy name. If you like one of them, you can add this line to your `.perlcriticrc`:

```
verbose = 8
```

(Or 9, if you prefer that format.)

Randy

Answer (score 5):

```
verbose = %f line %l col %c\n    [%s] %p (%e) = %m\n    %r\n
```

Season to taste. You're after `%p` or perhaps `%P`. The specifiers are documented in [perlcritic](http://p3rl.org/perlcritic).